# Micro Frontend Architecture in React Native Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, micro-frontend

I am creating a react-native application, And the application having many module like

- Login Module
- Payment
- Cart
- Product etc.

So I want to follow Micro Frontend Architecture for each module. I have searched on internet but did not find anything. So I want to know is it possible to achieve Micro Frontend Architecture for React-Native application. If yes then How ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Re.Pack](https://github.com/callstack/repack), which is Webpack toolkit for React Native. Since v3 it provides its own `ModuleFederationPlugin`, which allows you to set up Module Federation (MF) architecture of building micro-frontends.

Example MF app can be found here: https://github.com/callstack/repack-examples/tree/main/module-federation. It covers a basic example of 2 mini-apps loaded dynamically from a "host" app.

Comment: Adding this as a comment, but my team at Callstack is currently working on a more comprehensive showcase of using Module Federation for a sample Super App. We're gonna release it in OSS closer to March/April and followup with extra material on how to build such apps and what to expect and what not :)

Answer (score 2):

There are no proper solutions for RN Micro-frontend so far.
there are a few libraries that may help you to achieve this.

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-brownfield
**React Native Wix**

**But these are not recommended**

kindly go through this link so you will be more clear about your question.

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/jdpfrj/microservices_in_react_native/

Answer (score 2):

Microfrontends are concept originating from Web apps world. Achieving the same paradigm on mobile/React Native is possible, e.g. by using [Re.Pack](https://github.com/callstack/repack), but requires a quite complex setup. On the other hand, using Re.Pack will give you more app superpowers, like dynamically loading bundle splits from Internet.

As a simpler alternative, I would suggest setting up a monorepo containing separate NPM packages for each of the modules. This way you can achieve code separation more natural for mobile apps paradigm.